# Angular 1.x directive shared scope with controllerAs parent

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to create a directive that calls a method defined on the parent controller.

[I've made a plnkr here](https://plnkr.co/edit/LiCZftXcWqCdlDdvHK7y?p=preview)

I'm using controller as 'vm' for the parent controller. The method is not invoked on the directive tho. How can i call a method on the parent's controller from the directive?

```
(function() {
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

  myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

  MyCtrl.$inject = [];

  function MyCtrl() {
    this.title = 'Test';

    this.sayHello = () => {
      this.output = 'Hello';
    }

  }

  myApp.directive('sayHello', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      template: '<a href="#" ng-click="vm.sayHello();">Click to say hello</a>'
    }
  })
})();
```

Comment: I tested your plunkr, and this does call the parent function.

Comment: are you saying you get an output of Hello? Because I don't

Comment: Of course there isn't an output, you change the value of "output" to "Hello", use "console.log" or "alert()", you'll see that your function is called, see : https://plnkr.co/edit/3S5bglFxi0ifsx6uyMJT?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've change the code, and now its working:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp">
      <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
      <h3>{{vm.title}}</h3>
      <say-hello></say-hello>

      <h4>{{vm.output}}</h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```